# If time and date before php

Tags: php, date, time

I found this snippet here.

```
$resttimefrom = 50000; // 5am
$resttimeto   = 170000; // 5pm
$currentTime  = (int) date('Gis'); // time now

if ($currentTime > $resttimefrom && $currentTime < $resttimeto)
{
  // its before 5pm lets do something
}
else
{
  // after 5pm sorry
}
```

This worked perfectly fine but I would like to limit it by date also for the site I am working on I want it to check a timestamp if delivery = tomorrow then they must cancel the order before 5pm the day before.

Comment: Why don't you use appropriate types, use DateTime. http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Comment: I suggest using mktime or strtotime and just compare the timestamps.

Comment: You can use date('Gis', time()) to get time and date('d',time()) to get date for comparison(where time() = current timestamp. use mktime()/strtotime to get custom timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$timestamp = time();

$date = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
$time = date("G", $timestamp);

$tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('tomorrow'));

if ($date == $tomorrow && $time > 5 && $time < 17) {
    // It is in-between 5am and 5pm tomorrow.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (time() >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d', time()).' 5:00:00') && time() <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d', time()).' 17:00:00'))    {
    //  today between 5AM and 5PM
}
    else {

    }
```